# Issue with ant fork

Tags: java, ant, build

we are using fake ant (our own ant script in perl that sets some environment variables and then calls the actual ant) to run a java program. The program checks whether a server is running on a url or not(the server is running on localhost). It has to provide some security certs before it can communicate with the server since it is communicating over ssl. I have this java target in the build file

`<java classname="com.salesforce.util.ReleaseStoreValidator" fork="true" failonerror="true">`

The program works fine. The problem however is that we want to remove the fork, since it seems unnecessary. but removing the fork causes problems and results in this error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error

and the server also throws this warning log

> WARN:oeji.nio:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

I am not able to relate this problem with fork and cant solve it, any ideas ?

Comment: I don't understand the "fake Ant" part. Are you using Ant or not? If you're using your own Ant clone, how can people help with this sort of thing; this is essentially debugging invisible code. And how can a Perl script launch a Java program without forking?

Comment: its a perl script that sets some environment variables and then calls the actual ant with those environment variables

Comment: The program runs fine without the fork if I replace it with a helloworld program.

Comment: Ah, OK! That makes way more sense.

Comment: When you `fork`, you can launch a different JVM installation than the one Ant is running in. That's the first thing I'd check: perhaps your forked programs are running in a JVM with bad SSL support. Make sure your JAVA_HOME and PATH both point to the Java installation you're using to run Ant.

Comment: But the programs work fine with fork, its the absence of fork that causes issues. Also running from eclipse works fine too.

Comment: Oh, sorry. So same comment, just backwards: make sure you're running Ant with the same JVM that's being launched via `fork`.

Comment: One experiment: use your "fake ant" script to start that program, and check if it works.